# External data move to Azure cloud and call web API through Sharepoint online, Please suggest approach

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, azure, azure-ad, webapi

I want to move external data to Azure through web API. I am able to deploy web API in Azure but how to call web API through SharePoint online?

Or can we use SharePoint hosted apps for entire scenario without web API?

Please help me and suggest any approach.

Answer (score 1):

To call external Web Api from SharePoint Online, make sure CORS (cross origin resource sharing) is enabled for your SharePoint Domain.[image]